# Versioning containers in Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, versioning

I am new to Azure, and my data is in blob storage. I like to keep versions of changes not only at the file level (blob) but also at the container level. For example, in the below picture, I want to keep versioning "streaming-data".
[image]

Also, I like to keep versions of directories inside the container; in the below picture, I want to keep versions "week 1" and "week 2, 2,", where each contains several files. So if a file in a directory changes, I get a new version of "week1".
[image]

Is this possible, and how? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the platform allows you to do this automatically.

Depending on your use case. You can [subscribe to changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview) on changes to your storage account, then do the versioning yourself.